# UEFI script to programatically select boot OS

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, uefi

Is it possible via UEFI scripting or EFI applications to programatically select which Linux OS to boot from based on the state of UEFI variables?

I am trying to achieve a form of recovery system where on each boot the script checks if the last boot was successful. If it wasn't then it would reformat and restore from a read-only backup partition.

If it isn't recommended to do it this way. Does anyone have some suggestions on how best to implement a recovery system like this?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. I'm not sure it's worth doing it that way, though -- you can build an EFI binary that boots a kernel with a built-in initrd and do all the logic from there, including pivoting into your final system to boot (or kexec'ing a different kernel or whatever else you need). Presuming you're actually handy with Linux, it's likely to be a much friendlier environment. And since it's an immutable signed binary (assuming Secure Boot), you don't need to worry about corruption.

Comment: That said, if you want to look at a working, live, production-quality robust embedded OS with cryptographic verification, recovery, &c. ChromeOS is your friend.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using an EFI binary as opposed to using CONFIG_EFI_STUB and loading the kernel+initrd in the first step?

Comment: `CONFIG_EFI_STUB` is actually how I would suggest building that binary. :)

Comment: Do you happen to know what should be passed to CONFIG_CMDLINE? I'm a little confused around the initrd and root options as currently with nothing set I get a kernel panic with error about missing /dev/console and "Please ensure your rootfs is properly configured"

Comment: That's more a matter of what's in the init script in your initrd.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to specify USE_DEVFS=0 in Yocto. I have another question though :) When using pivot_root how would you ever update the kernel? My understanding is you only pivot to a new rootfs but keep using the same EFI kernel. In terms of SW updates this makes things pretty tricky unless the kernel in EFI boot partition can be updated from the real rootfs??

Comment: The EFI partition is just FAT, so that's not exactly hard to modify. And even if it's on immutable storage, you can switch kernels at runtime -- see kexec.

Comment: Just to let you know I got EFI kernel+initrd+kexec all working! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.